# Find out rows with NULL column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in my SQL Server database:

**TableOld**

```
Name    Id
--------------
User1   NULL
User2   NULL
User3   1
User4   2
User5   3
```

**TableNew**

```
Name    Id
-------------
User1   NULL
User2   NULL
User3   NULL
User4   NULL
User5   NULL
```

How do I find out new users with `NULL` values in `TableNew` - User3, User4, User5?

Comment: Null in only TableNew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to join your tables and filter with simple `where`: column `id` of new table to be `NULL`, column `id` of old - non `NULL`.

You can do this with this query:

```sql
SELECT tnew.Name
FROM TableNew tnew
JOIN TableOld told ON tnew.Name = told.Name
WHERE told.Id IS NOT NULL AND tnew.Id IS NULL;
```

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'to'` (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/6Zb1t8tA)  and: [RESERVED WORDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) )

Comment: I need Null in only TableNew

Comment: @user989988, exactly. This query will return names which have null in TableNew and have not null in TableOld. Check [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RSgETm1p)